# What is the purpose of a `transient do` block in FactoryBot factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

What is the purpose of `transient do` in FactoryBot factories?

I've seen a lot of factories that begin with something like below.

```
factory :car do
  owner nil
  other_attribute nil
end
...
```

I've found some information on this blog:
[Using FactoryGirl to easily create complex data sets in Rails](https://web.archive.org/web/20180403000920/http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2014/12/using-factorygirl-easily-create-complex-data-sets-rails/)

But I still don't fully understand how and why to do this. My experience with FactoryBot is minimal.

Could anyone with some experience using FactoryBot share some insight?

Comment: Your example doesn't use `transient`. Do you have a factory that uses `transient` that you want to understand?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`transient` attributes allow you to pass in data that **isn’t an attribute** on the model.

Say you have a model called `car` with the following attributes:

- name
- purchase_price
- model

You want to capitalize the name of the car when you create the car model in the factory. What we can do is:

```
factory :car do
  transient do
    # capitalize is not an attribute of the car
    capitalize  false
  end

  name           { "Jacky" }
  purchase_price { 1000 }
  model          { "Honda" }
 
  after(:create) do |car, evaluator|
    car.name.upcase! if evaluator.capitalize
  end
end
```

Hence, whenever you create the car factory and you want to capitalize the name. You can do

```
car = FactoryGirl.create(:car, capitalize: true)
car.name
# => "JACKY"
```

Answer (score 14):

Transient attributes are essentially variables local to the factory that do not persist into the created object.

I have seen two main uses of transient attributes. In both cases, they let a test create an object by expressing concepts (similar to a trait), without knowing anything about the implementation. These two examples are easy to understand, without knowing any object internals:

```
FactoryBot.create(:car, make: 'Saturn', accident_count: 3)
FactoryBot.create(:car, make: 'Toyota', unsold: true)
```

These two examples use transients for in distinct ways:

- Controlling/altering the creation of related objects (e.g. accident_count).
- Altering values assigned to other attribute assignments (e.g. unsold).

Inside the factory, those two transients are used like this:

```
factory :car do
  transient do
    accident_count 0
    unsold false
  end

  owner unsold ? 'new inventory' : nil

  after(:create) do |car, evaluator|
    create_list(:police_report, evaluator.accident_count, vehicle: car) 
  end      
end
```

The two attributes in the `create` call (`accident_count` and `unsold`) are not part of the model and are not explicitly saved...but both have effects on the resulting objected created for the test. *That* is the essential distinction of a transient, vs a trait or explicit attribute value.

IMO, I would stick with traits when they work (e.g. unsold, above). But when you need to pass a non-model value (e.g. accident_count), transient attributes are the way to go.